environment variable not read in sed
I am trying to update sudoers via script and passing the value of $HOSTNAME and it's not working... Obviously missing something.
I am expecting:
%mydomain-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%MYHOST-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

Below are the many attempts and results:
sed -i "/#My Customization.*/a%mydomain-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL\n""%"${HOSTNAME}"-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" /tmp/sudoers.bak1

%mydomain-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

sed -i "/#My Customization.*/a%mydomain-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL\n%${HOSTNAME}-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" /tmp/sudoers.bak1

%mydomain-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

sed -i "/#My Customization.*/a%mydomain-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL\n%"${HOSTNAME}"-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" /tmp/sudoers.bak1

%mydomain-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

sed -i "/#My Customization.*/a%mydomain-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL\n%'${HOSTNAME}'-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" /tmp/sudoers.bak1

%mydomain-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%''-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

sed -i "/#My Customization.*/a%mydomain-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL\n%'$HOSTNAME'-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" /tmp/sudoers.bak1

%mydomain-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%''-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

sed -i "/#My Customization.*/a%mydomain-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL\n%"$HOSTNAME"-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" /tmp/sudoers.bak1

%mydomain-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

sed -i '/#My Customization.*/a%mydomain-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL\n'"%{$HOSTNAME}"'-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL' /tmp/sudoers.bak1

%mydomain-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%{}-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

sed -i '/#My Customization.*/a%mydomain-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL\n%'"$HOSTNAME"'-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL' /tmp/sudoers.bak1

%mydomain-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

sed -i "/#My Customization.*/a%mydomain-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL\n%""${HOSTNAME}""-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" /tmp/sudoers.bak1

%mydomain-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%-localadmin@mydomain.net ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL


There you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Learn to use cmd-line debugging by executing set -x on cmd line. You will see your cmd preceded with + which shows you exactly how the shell is interpreting your provided syntax. Many/most dbl-quoted strings get converted to "hard" strings with single quotes. ALSO, learn to boil your question down to something that will fit in one line (if possible). yes, maybe #,%s are causing a problem, but they can be demo'd in smaller strings. Your first attempt looks best, but why are you breaking the string up with multiple open/closing " chars? Just make the cmd all one string. Good luck.

I have spent hours reading similar posts and attempting to fix, what appears to be a “simple” line of code.

read the 1-minute [tour] which will help you on how this site works. And check out the help center. Markdown is a requirement if you do anything with code, because almost all websites and apps like slack, github, reddit... use it for formatting. You have to learn it

Was writing an answer, but then your first line worked for me when using echo "#My Customization blah blah" | sed '/My ... (leaving out the -i and the filename) and I got results that looked appropriate. You can delete all the other attempts, the question is why isn't the first one working. AND please confirm that the problem is that value of $HOSTNAME is NOT appearing in your output. If  you remove all the extra dbl-quotes in your cmd and have just sed "....." file AND THEN there is still not HOSTNAME value, then HOSTNAME is not set. Add `echo HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME before you run the sed

.... Get this to work on the cmd-line first using echo "...." | sed "..." will speed up your turn-around time AND use the set -x as mentioned before. Good luck.

so what is the output of echo $HOSTNAME?

Note that the headline "environment variable not read in sed" is a bit misleading, and may be the source of some confusion. sed does not read any environment variables other than COLUMNS, LANG, LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE, and LC_COLLATE (may vary with implementation).  What you are doing trying to do is have the shell expand  the variable HOSTNAME and pass it as an argument to sed.  sed is not reading that value from its environment and whether it is in the environment of the shell is irrelevant.

[edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with a complete sample input file and expected output. Show the value of HOSTNAME and do not use the -i option with sed when trying to debug a problem as that'll just repeatedly trash your input.
